# Как отформатировать значения общего формата в значения даты.Парсинг xls таблицы?

Tags: c#, unity3d, xls, xlsx

Парсится таблица, но даты парсятся в общем формате.Парсить сразу в нужном - не вариант(библиотека не позволяет). Нужен метод для конвертации из общего формата в формат даты(входные выходные желательно строки) , к примеру "43506" в "10.02.2019  0:00:00"

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: о сборке :  сборка Excel, Version=2.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93517dbe6a4012fa

Comment: `"43506" в "10.02.2019 0:00:00"` у меня нет идей, какая между этими двумя строками связь

Comment: проблемаа решена , связь есть